# Getting attribute error : module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to use json_normalize function to flatten the JSON data. While calling the function I am getting this exception in Python;

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'
```

I'm using Python 3.8-Azure ML and used this;

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

How can we import this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

```
from pandas import json_normalize
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Answer (score 1):

`json_normalize` is coming from pandas [directly](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

So what you have to import is:

```
from pandas import json_normalize
```

Comment: tried that, but still getting an error;
\
ImportError: cannot import name 'json_normalize'

Comment: what pandas version you have btw ?

Comment: Python 3.6-Azure ML

Comment: Pandas version, not python. You can do smth like `import pandas as pd` and then `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: sorry, its 0.25.3

Comment: @kaolos, Tried updating panda version, by running this;

conda update pandas

getting this error, 

"PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix"

Comment: upgraded pandas version to 1.2.4. now its working fine

Comment: ah cool nice. your version was a bit old and was trying to set up a venv with it to check your issue out of curiosity

Comment: appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

try to upgrade pandas.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Edit:
The json_normalize() function was introduced in pandas 0.19.2. If you are getting this error then you might be using an older version.

Comment: Please explain why you think this solves the issue.

Comment: The json_normalize() function was introduced in pandas 0.19.2. If you are getting this error then you might be using an older version.